# Why can't I see the pictures dynamically in the Navigation bar?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

Why can't I see the pictures dynamically in the Navigation bar?

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    
    
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 20))
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    
    imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: currentFirma?.goruntuUrl ?? "")) { image, _, _, _ in
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.titleView = UIImageView(image: image)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use relevant tags when posting a question. This has nothing to do with Xcode, Flutter, or SwiftUI.

Comment: What is `sd_setImage(with:)`?

Comment: you've got several cases of optional chaining in your code. Have you either added print statements to log the values you are getting, or run your code in the debugger and looked at the values? If something is nil your code will silently stop.

Comment: `imageView` will be thrown away when `viewDidAppear` returns probably before the image is fetched, since it is a local image. Even if the closure does run you have quite the optional chain. If any of those are nil then the image view will not be added.

Comment: @DuncanC `sd_setImage` is part of the [SDWebImage](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage) library. Rather than calling this method on a throw-away UIImageView, the OP should use the [image manager directly](https://sdwebimage.github.io/documentation/sdwebimage/sdwebimagemanager)

Comment: Paul, good call on the image view being a local variable with no strong references. You should add that as an answer, along with a mention of the very fragile optional chain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your viewController is embedded inside a navigationController and  write the code like this

```
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 20))
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
navigationItem.titleView = imageView
imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: currentFirma?.goruntuUrl ?? ""), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "")) // make sure to add a placeholder for better UX
```